# Closure Compiler (advanced mode) -- How to design classes?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a class that has roughly this structure:

```
function MyClass() {
    // constructur stuff
}

MyClass.prototype.myFunc = function () {
    // example function
};

MyClass.myStaticFunc = function () {
    // example static function
};
```

I spent some time now setting up the closure compiler annotations and finally got rid of all warnings. And what do you know, it reduces the size by a spectacular 100%. So then I read about exporting functions, but `window['MyClass'] = MyClass` will only export the constructor. To be honest, I'd rather not export every single method individually. I thought the compiler would export and not obfuscate all publicly available methods but those with a `@private` annotation.

What's the best way to teach the closure compiler to do that and not have to export every method individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer: I can annotate methods with `@export` and run the compiler with `--generate_exports`. But maybe someone has an even better way.

Comment: `@expose` is your "better" way.

Comment: Could you explain why it is better than @export? @expose will prevent any optimization, which is definitely bad. And as the docs say: "@expose should never be used in library code"

Comment: That statement is there because `@expose` prevents renaming and dead code elimination. It is "better" than `@export` because it doesn't require a special flag at compilation time. Of course if you are writing a library for others to consume, then you should be using neither in the main code. Exports should be at the end of the code or better in a separate file because they block renaming and dead code elimination.

Comment: Why does `@export` block renaming? I can't see that happening in my output, it seems to work just fine. As for dead code elimination, I can't tell right now, because I don't have dead code (yet). The way I understand it, `@exports` should be equivalent to "manually" exporting methods, which, by the way, I'm trying to avoid, as I don't like the idea of having exports somewhere else in the code (error-prone); annotations I see right where I write my method.

Comment: Also: I don't mind the additional compiler flag. That's what they're there for ;)

Comment: `@export` both renames the property and preserves an reference to the original name - producing code similar to `foo.a=1;foo['prop']=foo.a;`. `@export` produces `foo.prop=1`. If you have lots of internal references to `foo.prop`, then `@export` will produce smaller gzip results. If `foo.prop` is mainly for external consumption, then `@expose` will produce smaller results. This is why I put better in quotes - it depends on usage.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I might compare them sometime, but for now I'm going with `@export`. :)

Comment: `@expose` is now deprecated. `@export` is now officially the correct method.

Comment: I ran through a few experiments here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-the-closure-compiler---advanced_optimizations

Answer (score 2):

Using `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` you must export EVERY public method and property. If you do not want the public methods and properties renamed, then use `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS`.

See my [Which Compilation Level is Right for Me](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html) post for more details.

Comment: But the advanced options do much more than that, which is why I want to use them. Anyhow, using the export annotation worked like a charme (see my own answer).

Comment: Advanced Optimizations does dead-code removal on the global space. That's the only other major difference.